# CSS :hover image switch with child selectors

Tags: html, css

I'm using only CSS to switch images on hover using child selectors. Each image is displayed as an inline-block within a containing div, creating a grid of images.

It is working beautifully, except for a weird twitch—

a.) when the the mouse hovers over the **first** image in the containing div; *AND* b.) when the page has scrolled any distance, the entire page jumps back up to the top.

This twitch is only provoked by hovering over the first image; it does not occur when the mouse moves between any other images, regardless of position.

The effect is visible here: https://jsfiddle.net/continuist/kognrzof/9/

CSS:

```
/* CONTAINER DIV */

    #rocks {width: auto;}

/* EACH IMAGE ELEMENT */

    .foo img {width:30%;} 

    .foo img:first-child{display:inline-block;}
    .foo img:last-child{display:none;}

    .foo:hover img:first-child{display:none;}
    .foo:hover img:last-child{display:inline-block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="rocks">
    <a class="foo" href="#">
       <img src="/img/item1.png">
       <img src="/img/item1hover2.svg">
    </a>
    <a class="foo" href="#">
       <img src="/img/item1.png">
       <img src="/img/item1hover.svg">
    </a>
    <a class="foo" href="#">
       <img src="/img/item3.png">
       <img src="/img/item3hover.svg">
    </a>

    ...

</div>
```

In the photo, each of these images switches on :hover. But when the page scrolls, and the mouse hovers over the FIRST image (the topmost, leftmost) on the page, the entire page jumps back to the top.

[image: Screenshot of the CSS/HTML above]

Comment: create a JsFiddle.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from what you've included because there is nothing obviously wrong. A Fiddle or a link to the working site/demo would help

Comment: Thanks Muhammad and FluffyKitten. I've created a JsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/continuist/kognrzof/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I thought it is your browser problem, because in firefox, the behavior was correct. However in Opera and Chrome, it was as bad as you describe.

I have created a fiddle, that seems to be working, however I recreated the code a little bit to be more clean.

Major change is, that I encapsuled the IMGs into div with given classes to handle hovering and size effects. Then the image is simply 100% of width of the div (also you may rather want to have the image as the background of the div to use the cover/contain sizes or better use of background-position rather than positioning the IMG element with overflow:hidden to the divs.

Also I made the A (.foo) float with margin:5px and width/height:calc(33vw - 15px), where the boxes will always be 3 on the row no matter what resolution you have (can be then handeled with media queries

```css
/* CONTAINER DIV */

    #rocks {width: auto;}
    
/* EACH IMAGE ELEMENT */

     .foo {width:calc(33vw - 15px); height:calc(33vw - 15px); position:relative; margin:5px 5px 0 0 ; float:left; } 
     .foo div img{width:100%;}
   
    .nd{display:none;}
    
    .foo:hover div.st{display:none;}
    .foo:hover div.nd{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="rocks">
<!-- ROW 1 -->
    <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a>
     <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a>
<!-- ROW 2 -->
    <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a>
<!-- ROW 3 -->
   <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a> <a class="foo" href="#">
    <div class="switch st"> <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nduc0f6fi6zmt5g/rock1.png?dl=0"></div>
      <div class="switch nd"><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/jce22cboubyv3l8/rock1-hover.png?dl=0"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/14h4z5uw/4/

Comment: This solution worked. I decided to apply this method (removing the class 'switch' which was undefined in the fiddle). I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: sure, glad to help :)  just note for the switch class. I used targeting by element `.foo:hover div.st{display:none;}` but it is better to use the class instead `.foo:hover .switch.st{display:none;}` ... it is not the problem of altual behavior, both solutions will work the same, but from experience, if you will target things like that and then, later, you will come back to your project and you add some other div element into the structure, the ruels will be applied to them aswell while targeting by div and this is not the wanted result in most cases :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to explain the reason of this behaviour, but I think I know the solution to your problem.

If you add `display: inline-block` to each `#rocks a` element you could solve it. 
Because of this change, you will have to switch the `width` applied to the images, to the anchor tags. I've forked your Fiddle and you can view it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbfbg07y/1/)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This solution worked also, with minimal alteration to the existing code (which reflects the way that my mind structures the problem). Thank you so much for the help!